# Erro plugin Facebook não conta quantidade de comentários

Tags: javascript, facebook, plugin, comentários

Usei o plugin do facebook em meu site, para os botões de curtir (like), compartilhar (share), caixa de rostos (facepile) e comentários (comments).

Tudo funciona, com exceção do contador de comentários em cada post, todos os códigos estão corretos, usei este script em português que o facebook disponibiliza:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=300497003454434&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

O estranho é que se eu usar o script em inglês, tudo funciona, só fica a descrição dos botões em inglês:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Como faço para o script em português exibir a quantidade correta de comentários?

Comment: Você esta usando o primeiro com o ID do seu APP.
Mas já tentou trocar:

`js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";`

Por: `js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js#xfbml=1";` ?

Comment: Sem o ID do aplicativo ele carrega do mesmo jeito que o script com idioma en_US, se eu limpar o cache e carregar a página, até conta os comentários, mas os plugins like and share não funcionam, porém isso parece ser um problema nativo do plugin, pois várias outras páginas apresentam o mesmo problema, G+ > Fb.
Mas se eu criar um app do FB e linkar ele com o SDK do plugin tb n mostra a quantidade de comentários.

Comment: Sim, todo mundo sempre é zuado pela API do Facebook, é normal isso. Mas precisa ver, não poderia ter mais de um código do SDK na sua página, tudo que funcionar com apenas um, se tiver usando mais de um pode causar esse comportamento mesmo.

Comment: Eu sei, só estou usando um código do SDK, Bom mesmo é do google q tem um suport e documentação muito melhor, além de carregar uma 10x mais rápido, se eu limpar o cache e recarregar a página os plugins do FB n carrega, só na segundo fez q eu atualizar, triste...

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.